# Use of __openerp__.py file in openerp7?

Tags: odoo

What is the use of Use of **openerp**.py file in openerp7.I understand the usage of *init*.py file.for my custom module how it is useful?

Comment: Refer this openerp doc: https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_4_module_development/module_descriptor/ https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/ro/developer/2_4_module_development/module_structure/#openerp-module-descriptor-file-openerp-py Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The `__openerp__.py` file is the OpenERP descriptor which contains a single Python dictionary with the actual declaration of Module. It is necessary file for an openerp module. All the details, dependencies, files used etc are specified here in the `__openerp__.py` file. Here is Python dictionary key description

- name :- Name of Module like 'Sale'
- version :- Version of Module like '1.0'
- author :- Name of author like who develop this module
- category :- Name of Module category like 'Accounting'
- website :- Website of a Module
- depends :- It's take a list of dependencies, when module install first install the depends modules
- description :- Description of the module
- summary :- summary of the module.
- data :- Data file where we define .xml file path
- demo :- Use for demonstration data,  if database uses demo data, then it will load.
- test :- test data(yaml testing, Unit testing) for this module,
- active :- Where to install automatically at new Database creation.
- installable :- Whether module is installable or not
- auto_install :- When all the dependencies are installed, then this module will automatically install if its true.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Odedra, In the module http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mmakonnen/addons-hr-ng/7.0/view/head:/hr_policy_absence/__openerp__.py inside the `depends` there is `hr_holidays` but I was unable to find a standalone module by that name. What is happening? Thanks

Comment: `hr_holidays` is a community module. It is available in your core module list. You may find in your addons directory.

Comment: I did. So the core modules are not displayed under the apps listing?

Comment: Yes, just remove apps filter from the search view and write down module name and hit enter. You will get that module.

Answer (score 0):

The **openep**.py file is like the setup.py file in Python modules. You need it in every module